# Use C#(Visual Studio 2019) to receive input but use C function to process

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio

I have created a C# application to receive input from user, after I want to process the input and pass to C function to process it. But unfortunately I failed. For example, user browse image from the C# and then how I pass it to the C code? Please help me to link it. Thank you.

```
    C function 
    __declspec(dllexport) int main() {
    FILE* fpBMP, * fpTwoValue;

fileHeader* fh;//Bitmap file header 
infoHeader* fi;//Bitmap information header 
rgbq* rg;//Palette 

int i, j, k = 0;
unsigned char* a;//store the pixel value of each row of the source image 
unsigned char b;//store the gray value or binary value of each pixel 
unsigned char* c;//store the binary value of each row of pixels 

/*Open the source file and create the output file */
if ((fpBMP = fopen("C:/Users/User/Downloads/sample2.bmp", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf("file open failed");
    exit(0);
}

if ((fpTwoValue = fopen("C:/Users/User/Downloads/sample_output.bmp", "wb")) == NULL) {
    printf("file create failed");
    exit(0);
}
```

}

```
C# 
    private void btnFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // open file dialog   
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        // image filters  
        open.Filter = "Image Files(*.bmp)|*.bmp";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // display image in picture box  
            coverImageBox.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Stego-image is only for BMP image format.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try to compile c to dll and then import this to c# or i think thats not good idea but still think is viable, just compile c to console app and then run this console app with some arguments from c# code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).